# Converting .obj object into XAML using HelixToolKit?

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I am new to WPF(3D) and HelixToolKit, I want to convert my .obj file into XAML code, I searched the entire library for the conversion of .obj to XAML but I didn't find anything to that, From which class file I can get this conversion code any idea?

Comment: HelixToolKit provides the built method for such conversion i.e. Export() method of HelixViewport3D, with the parameter name and extension of required file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the C# code behind rather than XAML for loading .obj files.

More information can be found here:
[How to import a 3D model in WPF using Helix Toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295195/how-to-import-a-3d-model-in-wpf-using-helix-toolkit)